# DIV overlap IMG IE 8

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm using a div with `position: fixed` to overlap an image.  This works fine in firefox, but not in IE8.  The div just sits below the image, even if I play with the top and left parameters.

**[Example of my Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/nBk79)**

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Could you throw in some code? and maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: ok, so what I want I want is this jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/nBk79 The problem with using relative is that it leaves whitespace behind. The problem (I've found) with absolute is that the position differs with different screen sizes. I want that toolbar to always sit where it is (I've put it slightly too high to show the bottom of the picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the only way but should give you good starting point at least.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EREc7/ - Parent element that has `position: relative;` makes sure that the element with `position: absolute` being the overlapping div would stick with the image no matter where you put the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EREc7/1/ - The same with border

---

You can also do something like this:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 4 /* The higher the number the higher the element is. make sure to*/
top: -50px;
left: 0px;
```

---

And something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EREc7/3/

---

Note that the first one is the most flexible one.

---

Here's a bit bigger example

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EREc7/4/

---

Examples from the comments:

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/nBk79/1

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/nBk79/6/

Comment: So will position: fixed not work?  I don't get the results I want with absolute.

Comment: @jdborg `fixed` does work the way that it works. But, its still not clear what you want to do.. Basically `position: fixed;` works the same way as `position: absolute;` difference being that `fixed` sticks to the viewport in its set position Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EREc7/6/

Comment: ok, so what I want I want is this jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/nBk79 The problem with using relative is that it leaves whitespace behind. The problem (I've found) with absolute is that the position differs with different screen sizes. I want that toolbar to always sit where it is (I've put it slightly too high to show the bottom of the picture).

Comment: I don't want the bar to shrink, because it doesn't then span the whole picture.

Comment: @jdborg I dont understand how it is shrinking in that example? Do you mean that you dont want the toolbar to shrink _if_ the image width is smaller than some specific width?

Comment: Here's and example of what I think you mean. http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/nBk79/6/

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index if you're talking about layering over one another.  Then you can adjust them where you want and put one on top of the other.

Comment: It's not disappearing behind, just not overlapping.  It's lust as if i'd gone <img src="foo.jpg"><br /><div>bar</div>

Comment: Z-index is designed to create things to 'overlap' one another (layer them).  So you could have an image, and then place text directly over that image if you so desired using z-index.  If you read up on z-index, I believe you have to have the elements positioned either relatively or absolutely in order for z-index to actually be useful.
Here is a little tutorial on it: http://www.echoecho.com/csslayers.htm

Comment: At least, what you're describing seems to be what z-index was meant for (overlapping/layering).  If you mean something else - can you try and clarify?

Comment: ok, so what I want I want is this http://jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/nBk79/ The problem with using relative is that it leaves whitespace behind.  The problem (I've found) with absolute is that the position differs with different screen sizes.  I want that toolbar to always sit where it is (I've put it slightly too high to show the bottom of the picture).

Comment: When you say 'leaves whitespace behind', are you talking about the white space surrounding the next and previous buttons?  You may want to try not using tables to set those buttons up - it may give you more control over how/where they display and give you better control over whitespace.  I just barely tinkered with it but you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nBk79/9/  - no whitespace and controls roughly where they were before (which you could adjust using CSS)